# Install trial version of Mathematica 9 next to genuine Mathematica 8

Tags: version-8, version-9

This morning I installed the trial version of Mathematica 9. After I discovered that `Export[]` is disabled in trial versions, I wanted to use my genuine Mathematica 8 again, but I discovered that the installer of MMA 9 apparently made MMA 8 a trial version too. When I try to re-register mma 8 it returns "You have already registered this product".

I'm running the student version of Mathematica 8.0.4.0 on Ubuntu 12.10 (64-bit).

**Question: How can I make Mathematica 8 fully functional again?**

Comment: If you have a backup look for the `mathpass` file. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RegistrationAndPasswords.html

Comment: Do you have a student version?

Comment: yes, student version

Comment: i don't have a backup file (at least couldn't find it).
In my mathpass files are two licenses: the top one seems to be the trial license, the bottom one my student license

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happened to me too and apparently, is a problem with the student version. [Arnoud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/105/arnoud-buzing) helped me figure out a work around for this. In your `$UserBaseDirectory/Licensing`, you should find a `mathpass` file that looks something like this:

```
(*userregistered*)
machineName1 ID ActivationKey1 Expiration1 UserName
machineName2 ID ActivationKey2 Expiration2 UserName
```

The first line is (most likely) your activation for the trial, and *Mathematica* 8 for students apparently tries to use this activation key and converts it to a trial version.

In my case (OS X), *Mathematica* 8 kept crashing, and Arnoud suspects it's because it tries to bring up the trial window at startup, which does not exist. You seem to not have that issue, but the workaround (for now) is to comment out the activation line (with a `%`) for *Mathematica* 9 trial version when you're not using it and then launch *Mathematica* 8.

Oh, and the problem seems to be primarily with the front-end, as I can launch a *Mathematica* 8 kernel from the command line simultaneously with *Mathematica* 9. So if you only need it for computations, that's another option.

Comment: Your solution fixed the problem! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, i didn't experience any crashing due to this problem, mma 8 just worked as a trial version.

Comment: I get no crashes but otherwise the exact behaviour you mention with home edition; fixable the same way too. Did not try with premier license (from work)

Comment: Should i file a bug report at wolfram.com?

Comment: @A.Goossens I've already done it, and I spoke with Arnoud about it, so they're aware and it's documented.