# How to force mathematica v.9 and 10 notebooks to open in their respective front end

Tags: version-9, version-10, installation

I have version 9 and 10 installed on Windows 7. if I double click to open version 9 notebook, then it opens in version 10, how I can force a notebook to open in its respective front end.

I have installed both versions: with different init: [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28186/can-mathematica-9-peacefully-coexist-with-mathematica-8-on-windows)

Comment: The answer to this would depend on your operating system, and would need to be implemented outside of Mathematica.  Also note that notebooks do not necessarily contain information about which front end version saved them, and that the front end version is rewritten every time you save a notebook.

Comment: I was not able to deal with it, and it is annoying -.-. It seems to work on Win 8.1 though. [chat proof :)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16758154#16758154)

Comment: I have the same problems on Win7: Right-click > Open with MMa 9... It still opens with MMa10 :(

Comment: On OS X, launch the version of _Mathematica_ you want to use. Then double-clicking on any Finder icon for a notebook will open that notebook in the running version of _Mathematica_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer applies only to Windows.

Since the files have the same extension you will not be able to do this automatically without some kind of shell extension for that purpose.  However you can edit the context menu to add commands as needed.

Run `regedit.exe` and navigate to:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.nb
```

Note the value for `(Default)`, e.g.:

```
M-WIN-L.NB.10.0.0.5099521
```

Using that value navigate to the matching path, e.g.:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\M-WIN-L.NB.10.0.0.5099521\shell
```

Note the structure of the `open` Key and mimic it for the command you wish to add.

For example you might create the following tree (in RegEdit Export format):

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\M-WIN-L.NB.10.0.0.5099521\shell\open2]
@="&Open with v9"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\M-WIN-L.NB.10.0.0.5099521\shell\open2\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\9.0\\Mathematica.exe\" \"%1\""
```